# Should we trim value in textbox before saving into database

Tags: data, textbox

Suppose that there are textbox First name and Last Name.
Should we trim it before entering it into database
For example

```
First name "John      " -> trim to "John"

Last name  "Lennon  " -> trim to "Lennon"
```

Comment: I am not convinced this is really UX? The answer is yes, but not for UX reasons.

Comment: should it on stackoverflow ?

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu - not really. The answer is probably "yes", but there may be cases where you don't want to trim.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu StackOverflow would be better IMO. But it might depend why you are asking.

Comment: some people might want to save those space for some unique reason i overlooked.

Comment: This is off-topic for UX.SE and isn't detailed enough to be migrated over to StackOverflow so it's been closed off here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely...always trim data before storing it.
(P.S. This question really belongs on StackOverflow rather than here)